# Ext JS 4.2.1 - grid with paging - checkbox state lost

Tags: javascript, extjs, checkbox

I have an ExtJS grid that has a PagingToolbar for (remote) paging, and a checkbox column defined as:

```
{
    dataIndex : 'selected',
    xtype: 'checkcolumn',
    width : 60                      
}
```

However, if I check a box and then page forwards and backwards, the checkbox state is not saved - all the checkboxes are unchecked.

I guess since the store only contains data for the current page (from the server), I need some way of storing the state for rows that are not in the current page of data, and then reinstating the checkboxes when I return to that page.

Is there a best practice, or example of storing the checkbox state in the store while paging?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, that's so low-level work that no one has yet thought to make a "best practice" for it. E.g.

```
beforeload:function(store) {
    if(!store.checkedItems) store.checkedItems = [];
    store.each(function(item) {
        store.checkedItems[item.get("Id")] = item.get("selected");
    });
},
load:function(store) {
    if(!store.checkedItems) store.checkedItems = [];
    store.each(function(item) {
        item.set("selected",store.checkedItems[item.get("Id")]);
    });
}
```

or

```
beforeload:function(store) {
    if(!store.checkedItems) store.checkedItems = [];
    store.each(function(item) {
        store.checkedItems[item.get("Id")] = {selected: item.get("selected") }; // extensible if you want to keep more than one checkbox...
    });
},
load:function(store) {
    if(!store.checkedItems) store.checkedItems = [];
    store.each(function(item) {
        item.set(store.checkedItems[item.get("Id")]);
    });
}
```

Comment: Can you post the fiddle for the working solution?

Comment: @Maninder No, but you can create a fiddle with what you have, and I can try to do the necessary corrections.

Comment: Thanks for responding, just now I was able to enhance your solution and it worked fine for me. The issue was whenever I was going to next page of grid and comes back to previous page checkedItems variable was getting initialized back to empty as store was getting reloaded again. So I put those values in viewModel instead and made couple of more changes which helps me to solve the issue. Thanks anyway.

Comment: That is impossible unless the store is completely reinitialized for every page you load. Usually, the store data is replaced only, but the checkedItems property I added on the store itself should not be affected by store load.

Comment: Yes, so whenever I was pressing next to load the next page in the paging toolbar, whole store was getting refreshed. It can be due to version change as I am using 6.5.3. Anyhow your solution was helpful to find solution for my issue, that's I gave thumbs up to your answer.