# ExtJS infinite Grid styling

Tags: extjs, extjs5

I am trying to style rows of an ExtJS grid with ExtJs v5.1.0 and I am wondering if it is possible to style a row and have that style remain bound to the `<tr>` element or the record even when I scroll away and scroll back to my row.

An easier way to say it: scrolling away from a styled row removes the custom styles of that row. is there anyway to prevent this? possibly a BufferedStore session? Thank you in advance.

Comment: To add: I was thinking of having someway of keeping track of changed rows. Then on row render check if they were in my list of changed rows is that a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't directly style your rows. Instead, configure your grid's view to have a custom [`getRowClass`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.0-classic/Ext.view.Table.html#method-getRowClass) method.

```
Ext.create('grid', {
  viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function(record, rowIndex, rowParams, store){
      return record.get("valid") ? "row-valid" : "row-error";
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would have to keep book about the state of your columns somewhere. I already answered a similar question [about checkbox column state with paging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38241152/ext-js-4-2-1-grid-with-paging-checkbox-state-lost/38243057#38243057), you would have to do similarly for your row styles, and possibly also save/restore state in the `beforeprefetch` and `prefetch` events.